# Fixed scrolling position at rotation

Tags: android, scroll, rotation

I want to have a fixed scrolling position when I rotate my phone. Here is my code.

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivityFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String ARRAY_LIST = "list_view";
    private static final String LAYOUT_STATE = "MainActivityFragment.recycler.layout";
    ArrayList<Movie> movies;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private MovieAdapter movieAdapter;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

    public MainActivityFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_activity, container, false);

        if(savedInstanceState == null) {

            MovieDataService movieDataService = RetrofitInstance.getService();

            Call<MovieDBResponse> call = movieDataService.getPopularMovies(BuildConfig.MOVIESDB_API_KEY);

            call.enqueue(new Callback<MovieDBResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<MovieDBResponse> call, Response<MovieDBResponse> response) {
                    MovieDBResponse movieDBResponse = response.body();
                    Log.i(TAG, "inside retrofit");
                    if (movieDBResponse != null) {


                        movies = (ArrayList<Movie>) movieDBResponse.getResults();

                        recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.rvMovies);

                        movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity(), movies);

                        swipeRefreshLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipe_layout);
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorPrimary);
                        //swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(()-> getPopularMovies());

                        if (getActivity().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {

                            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2));

                        } else {
                            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 4));
                        }

                        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(movieAdapter);
                        movieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }


                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<MovieDBResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                }
            });

        }else{
            movies = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(ARRAY_LIST);

            recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.rvMovies);

            movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity(), movies);

            swipeRefreshLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipe_layout);
            swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorPrimary);
            //swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(()-> getPopularMovies());

            if (getActivity().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {

                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2));

            } else {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 4));
            }

            recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(movieAdapter);
            movieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelableArrayList(ARRAY_LIST,movies);
        outState.putParcelable(LAYOUT_STATE, recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState());

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
        if(savedInstanceState != null)
        {
            Parcelable savedRecyclerLayoutState = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(LAYOUT_STATE);
            recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(savedRecyclerLayoutState);
        }
    }
}
```

I am using onSaveInstanceState and onViewStateRestored methods but when I rotate the phone, the fixed scrolling position doesn't work. How to fix that?

Thanks,

Theo.

Comment: When you say "fixed scrolling position" do you mean a default position that is scrolled to, or do you mean you want to save off the location of where you were last scrolled to, and on rotate be able to scroll back to that position?

Comment: @CMcAllister I want to save off the location of where I where last scrolled to